# Mongo(3 shards) Driver C++: erro SyncClusterConnection

Tags: c++, qt, mongodb

Estou tendo problema para rodar o upsert no mongo quando conecto em 3 shards no cpp.
Agora quando conecto em apenas uma das shards eu consigo fazer a operação.
Alguem tem alguma alternativa ou sabe o motivo desse erro?

CODIGO:

```
ConnectionString cs("mongodb://host:pass@server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017", ConnectionString::ConnectionType::SYNC);

DBClientBase *conn = cs.connect( mongo_erro );
BSONObjBuilder bojUpsert;

bojUpsert.append("teste","1234567890");
bojUpsert.append("valor",123);

conn->update("xxx.xxx", Query("{teste:\"1234567890\"}") , bojUpsert.obj() , mongo::UpdateOptions::UpdateOption_Upsert);
```

ERRO:

> **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::UserException'
>         what():  SyncClusterConnection::update upsert query needs _id**

estou usando **linux mint**, **QT 4.8.6 + libmongo-client-dev 0.1.7-1**

Comment: Por que a tag "C"? Pelo que estou vendo, o seu código está em C++ e C++ é diferente de C